# how to use a unity lens without a reboot/logout

Tags: lenses, reboot, logout

How can I use a lens like the [unity-news-lens](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/05/unity-news-lens-helps-you-find-news-fast) without a reboot or logout?

Comment: If possible, please consider closing some of your other open questions by [selecting the best answer](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1137/how-do-i-accept-an-answer) (if they have one). Consider which answers have been useful and need an upvote. We need users to maintain their questions so that the site can be an effective tool for the next person with your problems. For more details on best practices consider reading [the FAQ on asking questions](http://askubuntu.com/faq#howtoask).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Press ALT-F2 and type

```
r
```

or

```
unity --replace
```

or

```
compiz --replace
```

Comment: This worked. But ALT-F2 is a better way. because that terminal has to stay open to keep using unity. i wasn't thinking i pressed CTRL-C when in the gnome-terminal. it shutdown my unity and i couldn't do anything. when pressed ALT-F2 an run unity --replace that just restart the unity without any opened window needed. And also compiz --replace works to. Edit you answer with the information i gave you and I'll accept it. Thank you

Comment: Done... ;) Be sure this is not a duplicate, as such a solution is very common...